# CloudKit Query with modificationDate Always Returns No Results

Tags: nspredicate, cloudkit, ckquery, ckqueryoperation

My goal is to get `User` records from CloudKit I specify in an array of `CKRecord.ID`s, but only if they were updated more recently than my last updated date which I track locally.

I'm doing the following CloudKit query:

```
var predicate:NSPredicate

if let lastChecked = defaults.object(forKey: "lastUserFetch") as? Date{
  //Subsequent fetches
  predicate = NSPredicate(format: "modificationDate > %@ AND recordID IN %@", argumentArray: [lastChecked, userRecordIDs])

}else{
  //First fetch
  predicate = NSPredicate(format: "recordID IN %@", argumentArray: [userRecordIDs])
}

let query = CKQuery(recordType: "User", predicate: predicate)
let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
...
```

I initially set `lastUserFetch` to `nil` when my app launches, and the "First fetch" part of the query succeeds. I get all the user records back.

But once I set my `lastUserFetch` date after the query is done:

```
defaults.set(Date(), forKey: "lastUserFetch")
```

I get `0` records returned when the `modificationDate > %@` portion is included. I, of course, modify records in the CloudKit Dashboard, and I can see that their `modificationDate` has updated and is newer than my `lastUserFetch` date, but they still don't get returned in my search results.

How do I combine a `modificationDate` comparison with a `recordID IN` query?

Comment: Ugh... for being so reliable, CloudKit sure is unreliable.  I tried this query on another record type and it worked. So I rebuilt my `User` record type by deleting it in the CloudKit dashboard and reconstructing it, and now it works again. Sheesh.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [NSCompoundPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscompoundpredicate):

```
var predicate:NSPredicate

//Every fetch
predicate = NSPredicate(format: "recordID IN %@", argumentArray: [userRecordIDs])

if let lastChecked = defaults.object(forKey: "lastUserFetch") as? Date{
  //Subsequent fetches
  predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [predicate,  NSPredicate(format: "modificationDate > %@", argumentArray: [lastChecked]))
}
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "User", predicate: predicate)
let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
...
```

Comment: That's a great suggestion, thank you. I tried it and unfortunately it still doesn't seem to work. I can do one of the `NSPredicate`s, but not both. So strange.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have queryable index created on modificationDate field on cloudKit

Comment: Please add an explanation.

Comment: Thank you for this note. I could not figure out why I kept getting zero back when using modificationDate in the predicate, but it was fine with creationDate. I set the indexes up so long ago, I forgot this requirement.